# F# for textual representation of a polynomial

Tags: f#

I need some help with the following:
Supposing a polynomial is given by

a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...

and that the coefficients are stored in a list [a_0; a_1; a_2; ...],

I want to write an F# function that gives a textual representation of a polynomial.
It's probably going to be recursive, but I can't see how at the moment. Any input?

Comment: I don't think the problem here is that question is "too easy". Everything is easy when you know how to do it. The problem is that question shows no effort to solve the problem. Nevertheless, the straight forward solution could look like this: `let c = [5;4;3;2;1]` 

`let f = c |> List.mapi (fun i x -> sprintf "%ix^%i" x i) |> List.reduce(fun x y -> x+"+"+y)`
This doesn't handle the case when x^0 = 1, so it's still displayed:" 5x^0+4x^1+3x^2+2x^3+1x^4"

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this to learn F# (or as a homework), then it is good idea to use recursion. You can start with the usual template for recursive processing of lists - where you iterate over coefficients, handle empty list and handle non-empty list.

The following shows the template, but it leaves the rest of the body to be filled, so that you are left with some challenge:

```
let coefficients = [5;2;7;4]

let rec format exponent coefficients = 
  match coefficients with 
  | [] -> ""
  | c::coefficients ->
      let rest = format (exponent + 1) coefficients
      // Now we have 'c', which is the current coefficient,
      // 'exponent', which is the current exponent and 
      // 'rest' which is the string representing the rest
      // of the polynomial. For example, for the sample above
      // we will at some point have:
      //
      //   rest = "4x^3"
      //   exponent = 2
      //   c = 7
      //
      // What code do we need to construct and return the 
      // final string, i.e. "7x^2 + 4x^3" ??
```

There are a few more things you might want to add to do this well:

- if `c = 0` then you'll want to drop the component rather than adding `0x^3`
- if `c = 1` then you'll want to add just `x^3`
- it will be easier to add a case handling the last coefficient `[c]` (so that you do not end up with a useless `+` at the end).